# Angle of Conical Pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, string

**Setup**

A ball of mass $m$ is attached to a string of length $L$. It is made to rotate at speed $\omega$ as a conical pendulum making an angle $\theta$ with the vertical.

**Question**

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/673057/what-causes-the-rotating-ball-on-a-string-to-rotate-upwards) post shows how the angle the ball makes is

$cos (\theta) = \frac g {L \omega^2}$

One would expect the angle $\theta$ to approach zero as $\omega$ approaches zero, but that is not what this solution shows. Can someone help me understand the above solution?

Thanks!

Comment: do not divide by zero, and you get the solution to your doubts

Answer (score 3):

When the angle $\theta$ gets small then
$$
\omega\to \sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}
$$
which is the angular frequency of  small amplitude swinging of a  simple pendulum with length $L$. The angular velocity $\omega$ cannnot get smaller than this value. The small-angle conical pendulum motion is just independant equal-amplitude $x$ and $y$ direction swings   that are 90 degrees  out of phase:
$$
x(t)= a \cos\omega t\\
y(t)= a \sin\omega t
$$

Comment: what allows you to conclude that $\omega$ cannot be less than $\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$? Is it simply because if that's true, $cos (\theta) = \frac g {L \omega^2}$ has no solution?

Comment: That's one way. The other is to understand how the conical pendulum is a special case of a simple pedulum that can swing in both the $y$ and $y$ directions.

Answer (score 1):

If $\omega$ is too small then the ball cannot “rotate upwards” (as asked in the linked question), *i.e.* the ball will execute the usual motion about the lowest point.

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166026/36194) contains additional technical details, but roughly speaking there is a critical minimum frequency so that the rotating pendulum is stable about some non-zero $\theta$ angle.  This is the gist of the linked question.  As your manipulations show, if you are blow this critical frequency, there is no angle $\theta$ for which $\cos\theta=g/(L\omega^2)$ because the right hand side is greater than 1.

When there is no solution the effect of the rotation is simply to reduce (but not overcome) the effect of $g$.  When $\omega^2$ is large enough, the centripetal force can overcome gravity and the pendulum can oscillate about some angle that is not at the bottom.

Comment: can you clarify what you meant by "When there is no solution the effect of the rotation is simply to reduce (but not overcome) the effect of $g$."

Comment: also, can you confirm the following. (1) If $\omega<\omega_c$, then the ball will oscillate about $\theta=0$ (like a simple pendulum). (2) If $\omega>\omega_c$ then the ball will oscillate about $\theta>0$.

Comment: Yes to your second.  To your first, see [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/320689/36194) to the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

the  equations [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/673057/what-causes-the-rotating-ball-on-a-string-to-rotate-upwards)

$$T\,\sin(\theta)=m\,\,r\,\omega^2=m\,L\,\sin(\theta)\,\omega^2\tag 1$$
$$T\,\cos(\theta)=m\,g\tag 2$$

if $~\omega\ne 0~$
then you obtain

$$T=m\,L\,\omega^2\quad,\cos(\theta)=\frac {g}{L\,\omega^2}$$

and if $~\omega=0~$ from equation (1)

$$T\,\sin(\theta)=0\quad\Rightarrow \theta=0$$

and from equation (2)

$$T=m\,g$$